# Consequences of changing the name of facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I will start the development of a new facebook app to replace an old one. I can create a new one and start from zero... or can I replace the code of the old one and change its name, to keep the users? It sounds weird to me, but could I?

Is there any consequence of changing the name of the app? Can I keep my users if I change the name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app name is purely for display purposes – changing it does not have any effects apart from what gets displayed to the user in the Auth dialog and other places where your app name gets displayed, f.e. posts made through your app (although for the latter it’ll also influence the displaying of previously made posts – they will show up as made via the new app name when viewed after the change).

> to keep the users?

But if you radically change the functionality, maybe you should “start fresh” – I don’t know how much I’d like it as a user when an app I used before now does something completely different …